# How to show server fetched data in app on another controller in swift

Tags: php, arrays, swift, uitableview

I used PHP api to get data from server. I created an array on AddCircleVC()

```
var CircleArray: [String] = []
```

When i login then server returns some circle names and that name i stored in this array like below:

```
if let UserArray = (json as AnyObject).object(forKey: "data") as? NSArray
{
   for UserDic in UserArray
   {
     if let circlename = (UserDic as AnyObject).object(forKey: "circleName") as? String
       {
          print("CircleName: \(circlename)")

          self.key.CircleArray.append(circlename)

           print("CircleArray: \(self.key.CircleArray)")
           UserDefaults.standard.set(self.key.CircleArray, forKey: "CircleArr")
           continue
           }
}
}
```

I want to show in these circle names in MenuVC(). So i used below code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0
    {
        print("CircleNumber:\(key.CircleArray.count)")
        if self.expandCell 
        {
           return ((self.selIndexPath) != nil) ? 1 : key.CircleArray.count
        } 
       else 
       {
            return key.CircleArray.count
        }
    }
    else if section == 1
    {
        return 7
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }

}
```

But every time when i login it prints circle number 0. How to show all circle names on MenuVC().

Comment: have you properly check that circlename is save in 'self.key.CircleArray'?

Comment: yes, i checked it prints all the circle names.

Comment: One more thing please tell are you parsing your JSON in VC or in someother file? and once you added all circlenames in array then you reaload tableview or not?

Comment: MenuVC().tableView.reloadData() i used this in SignInVC() where parsing json after UserDefaults.standard.set(self.key.CircleArray, forKey: "CircleArr")

Comment: please update your code.

Comment: and relaodTableview after this loop ends 'for UserDic in UserArray'.

Comment: Ok. I will Try and let you know.

Comment: it gives an error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity in your code thats why might I am wrong but what I understand is that you get `JSON` array in `AddCircleVC` and you want to show that `JSON` array in `MenuVC`.
So when you save all `circlename` in array. Simply pass this array to `MenuVC` like I have shown you in code given below.
And you always get `circle number 0` because in `MenuVC` `self.key.CircleArray` is empty.

```
class AddCircleVC : UIViewController {

  var CircleArray: [String] = []

  func buttonLogin() {
     parseJSON()
     let menuVC : MenuVC // Create Object of MenuVC
     menuVC.menuVcDataSource = CircleArray
     /// push MenuVC
  }

  func parseJSON() { 

if let UserArray = (json as AnyObject).object(forKey: "data") as? NSArray
{
   for UserDic in UserArray
   {
     if let circlename = (UserDic as AnyObject).object(forKey: "circleName") as? String
       {
          print("CircleName: \(circlename)")

          self.key.CircleArray.append(circlename)

           print("CircleArray: \(self.key.CircleArray)")
           UserDefaults.standard.set(self.key.CircleArray, forKey: "CircleArr")
           continue
           }
}
}
  } 

}

class MenuVC : UIViewController {
   var menuVcDataSource : [String] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0
    {
        print("CircleNumber:\(menuVcDataSource.count)")
        if self.expandCell 
        {
           return ((self.selIndexPath) != nil) ? 1 : menuVcDataSource.count
        } 
       else 
       {
            return menuVcDataSource.count
        }
    }
    else if section == 1
    {
        return 7
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Actually at 1st time my code is not working but when i stop my app and run again my code working fine

Comment: Now check again please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196429/how-to-show-fetched-data-first-time-in-swift Check this link